# Discord.py D&D dice roll command has far too many issues

Tags: python, discord, bots, discord.py, dice

So all of my D&D party members are convinced that the current dice bot is "cursed", so I decided to take matters into my own hands and make my own bot. It's cool and all, but I have multiple issues with my dice roll command.

The command I currently have is

```
async def d(ctx, die:int):
    for x in range(1):
        await ctx.send("<:d20:748302353375166614> "+str(random.randint(1,die)))
```

The first issue is that it uses the format "|d 20" instead of "|d20", so the first request would be getting rid of that space between the "d" and the int that indicates the number of sides the die would have ("die" variable, "20" in this example).

On top of this, I'd like to add a feature where if one types "|*[number of dice]*d*[number of sides]*", it'd roll the requested die the requested amount of times. If the number of dice isn't specified (eg.: "|d20"), it should automatically assume that the number of dice is 1. The bot message should include all the rolled numbers, and their sum.

For example "|2d20" might return "<:d20:748302353375166614> *11 + 15 =* 26", and "|10d2" might return "<:d20:748302353375166614> *1 + 1 + 2 + 1 + 2 + 2 + 2 + 1 + 1 + 2 =* 15"

AND on top of that, I'd also like the ability to be able to add bonuses to rolls ("|*[number of dice]*d*[number of sides]*+*[bonus]*") and return both the dice roll, the bonus, and the final value in the bot's message.

For example "|d20+4" might return "<:d20:748302353375166614> *11 + 4 =* 15", and "|2d10+2+3" might return "<:d20:748302353375166614> *9 + 4 + 2 + 3 =* 18"

(Optionally, things like "|1d4+2d6" could be made possible if the person painfully writing the answer to this question feels like they aren't in enough agony yet from the sheer size of this request)

Comment: what have you tried to do accomplish your goals? If you want a space removed, there's a whitespace literal in the string you passed - have you tried removing that? SO is not a place for us to provide an immediate *code solution* to your problems

Comment: Just here so say: D&D gooooo! And; You should create stickers for all 20 sides of the dice and let the bot post them when rolled. Would be awesome..

Comment: @TheodorPeifer At the moment I have 3 emotes, one for nat 1, one for nat 20, and one for everything between, but I decided not to use them for that it would be unnecessarily complicated using the current code. I also had this idea that first, it would just send an animated emote of a d20 rolling, and it'd only reveal the number after 2-3 seconds for suspense, but i scrapped that too because at this point I've had enough and I'm just glad it works as intended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the [`commands`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html?highlight=commands) extension, you can't get rid of the space between your command and the `die` variable. In order to get rid of it, you'd have to use an [`on_message`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=on_message#discord.on_message) event to parse your command's content:

```py
from random import sample

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    content = message.content
    if content.startswith('|') and (content[1].isdigit() or content[1]=='d'):
        content = content.split('+')
        rolls = [int(content.pop(i)) for i in range(len(content)) if content[i].isdigit()]
        for elem in content:
            n, faces = elem.split('d') if elem.split('d')[0] != '' else (1, elem[1:])
            rolls += [randint(1, int(faces)) for _ in range(int(n))]
        rolls_str = ' + '.join([str(n) for n in rolls]) 
        await message.channel.send(f"{rolls_str} = {sum(rolls)}")
    else:
        pass

    await client.process_commands(message)
```

Comment: I really appreciate this comment, but something seemed to go wrong, the log is the following:
```
2020-08-27T20:38:08.254349+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "namegen.py", line 21, in <module>
2020-08-27T20:38:08.254521+00:00 app[worker.1]:     @bot.event
2020-08-27T20:38:08.254546+00:00 app[worker.1]: NameError: name 'bot' is not defined
2020-08-27T20:38:08.335175+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Process exited with status 1
2020-08-27T20:38:08.368578+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from up to crashed
```

Comment: I have `client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "|")` written

Comment: So you just have to replace bot with client :)

Comment: Ok, it works almost perfectly, though it does roll a 0 occasionally so I'll have to work on that when i have some more spare time. Thank you.

Comment: It works, and also for those who are here looking for an answer, the bot now only generated numbers from 1-19 when requesting a d20 for example, but it can easily be fixed by doing `range(1, (int(faces)+1))`

It also only allows the number of dice to be a single digit number that is smaller than the amount of sides the dice have for some weird reason, but that's fine, I don't think anyone would be rolling 21d20s anyways.

Answer (score 1):

What about a format like `!roll 3d20+6d8+1`? If that's acceptable, you could do something like:

```
async def d(ctx, *args):
    dicestring = "".join(args)
    # Process dicestring here
```

Here, *args is a variable-length argument specifier. The way commands are parsed, `!roll 5d6 + 6d12` will give you arguments `("5d6", "+", "6d12")` but `!roll 5d6+6d12` will give you arguments `("5d6+6d12")`.

The `"".join(args)` will simply mush all those arguments together, leaving you with a string you can parse however you'd like.

If it's important to you that the only prefix is a |, the thing you're trying to do doesn't fit as neatly into the command structure. I'd look into making it an `on_message` event like https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord-api-events.